# How to calculate diametrically opposite point inside a circle?

Tags: math

x1,y1 is a point inside a circle (not in the circumference of the circle). How can I calculate the diametrically opposite point?

```
       |
       |   x1,y1
       |
-------|--------
       |
x2,y2  |
       |
```

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1:** Convert it to polar coordinates, and add pi to the angular part.

You'd basically use `atan2` (available in most languages) to compute the angle, and pythagoras formula to compute the radius.

**Option 2:** Compute the difference relative to origo, and add the negation of that to the origo point.

Let (ox, oy) be the center of the circle. Now the "opposite point" could be computed with

```
x2 = ox - (x1 - ox)
y2 = oy - (y1 - oy)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that the center is at (0,0), why wouldn't you just take (-x1, -y1)? If it is anything diferent, add the -x1, -y1 to the center coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question. But I'll give the asker a break and say:
(x2,y2) = f(x1,y1) where f is (x * -1, y * -1).

Answer (score 0):

If the center of the circle is at (0,0) then x2 = -x1, y2 = -y1.  If the center is at (xc, yc), then x2 = 2 xc - x1, y2 = 2 yc - y1.